# dockerのインストールがうまくいかない（windows10）

Tags: docker, windows-10

Windows 10 Pro (1903) で Docker for Windows のインストールを実施しましたが、
Windows PowerShell にて バージョンの確認ができません。
(特にエラーは発生していないので、正常にインストールされていると思います)

実装RAM 16GB

どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

パソコン上には、以下のように表示されます。

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker version
プログラム 'docker' の実行に失敗しました: この操作に対して指定されたファイルには、アプリケーションが関連付けられていま
せん。発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ docker version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ docker version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Docker が正しくインストールされていないか、pathが通っていないかだと思います。Docker のインストール先にpathが通っているか確認してみてください。

Comment: [`docker --version`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#test-your-installation)(`version`の前にハイフンが2つ必要)が正しいコマンドだと思いますが、こちらを実行しても同様でしょうか。

Comment: docker　--versionにしても同じです。

Comment: ただ、dockerのインストール後、アカウントの取得が「必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: また、pathの確認方法がよく分かりません・・・

Comment: バージョン表示できました。pathを設定しなおしたら出来ました。ありがとうございました。